# how to install nodejs nightly build to my Windows environment

Tags: node.js, windows

I would like to install a nightly build of node.js instead of the current release (8.3.0) into my Windows machine. With an installer how can I do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the one you want from here:
https://nodejs.org/download/nightly/

Comment: The question is what shoud I do to install the nightly. I cannot do it via nvm .